# OS/X: can't execute shell scripts - spawns a new window which exits immediately

Tags: bash, shell-script, osx, iterm

## **Issue:**

When I try to open any shell scripts a new window is spawned, which exits immediately. Files `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc` and a `helloworld.sh` are tested examples.

Interestingly, running `open helloworld.sh` outputs:

```
Jake:~ jakebanks$ /Users/jakebanks/helloworld.sh; exit;
Hello World!
logout
```

Which seems to say it executed successfully. The output of `echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]}` (in the first window) is `0`.

### **Config:**

Recently I changed my default terminal to iTerm2, and this is the most recent change I can recall making before having this issue.

- Default text editor is Sublime Text 2.
- Default shell is bash.
- FWIW, the issue is terminal agnostic.

Contents of `.bash_profile` are (for now):

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
export PATH
```

The contents of .bashrc:

```
#!/bin/bash
#THIS MUST BE AT THE END OF THE FILE FOR SDKMAN TO WORK!!!
export SDKMAN_DIR="/Users/jakebanks/.sdkman"
[[ -s "/Users/jakebanks/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh" ]] && source "/Users/jakebanks/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
```

### **What I've tried:**

- Changing shells
- Opening non-shell-script files (e.g. text files) with success
- Resetting profiles to their defaults in both Terminal and iTerm2

### **Solution:**

It turns out that I was confused about how shell scripts are invoked from the terminal. The command actually should have been `sh helloworld.sh`, rather than `open helloworld.sh`

Comment: You need to change your filetype associations (somehow).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have taken a look and it appears Sublime Text is set to be the default program for the .bash_profile and .bashrc extensions. Could this be a problem?

Comment: Right click on a file with the desired extension->get info->open with (change app), and click in "change all" and then "continue". Please in next posts, specify you are talking about OS/X at the beginning of the post.

Comment: Hi Rui, the difficulty I am having is now how to change the associations, but knowing which ones being set incorrectly could be causing my problem. Thank you.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro - it says, right at the top of the post, in the address bar: *unix.stackexchange.com*.

Comment: I commented it at Dec 12, and it was my edit ;)

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro - how did you edit my address bar?